# Dafny Proving sequence iteration equivalent

Tags: dafny

Starting with these two definitions:

```
function sumDown(nums: seq<int>): int {
    if |nums| == 0 then 0 else sumDown(nums[0..(|nums|-1)])+nums[|nums|-1]
}


function sumUp(nums: seq<int>): int {
    if |nums| == 0 then 0 else nums[0]+sumUp(nums[1..])
}
```

I am try to show that.

```
lemma sumsEqual(nums: seq<int>)
    ensures sumDown(nums) == sumUp(nums)
{}
```

I think I'm missing some obvious fact. Do I need to define a reverse method and then prove the reverse of sum is equivalent? Do I need to break the cases down by cardinality, one for empty and single, and the other for greater than 1 and then try to use induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to break the cases down by cardinality, one for empty and
> single, and the other for greater than 1 and then try to use
> induction?

This sounds like right way to tackle it. You might require additional lemma for example I needed to prove lemma that sumUp is distributive across sequence append.

```
function sumDown(nums: seq<int>): int {
  if |nums| == 0 then 0 else sumDown(nums[0..(|nums|-1)])+nums[|nums|-1]
}


function sumUp(nums: seq<int>): int {
  if |nums| == 0 then 0 else nums[0]+sumUp(nums[1..])
}

lemma sumUpLemma(a: seq<int>, b: seq<int>)
  ensures sumUp(a + b) == sumUp(a) + sumUp(b)
{
  if a == [] {
     assert a + b == b;
  }
  else {
    sumUpLemma(a[1..], b);
    calc {
      sumUp(a + b);
      {
        assert (a + b)[0] == a[0];
        assert (a + b)[1..] == a[1..] + b;
      }
      a[0] + sumUp(a[1..] + b);
      a[0] + sumUp(a[1..]) + sumUp(b);
    }
  }
}

lemma sumsEqual(nums: seq<int>)
  decreases |nums|
  ensures sumDown(nums) == sumUp(nums)
{
  if nums == [] {}
  else {
    var ln := |nums|-1;
    calc {
      sumUp(nums[..]);
      {
        assert nums[..] == nums[0..ln] + [nums[ln]];
        sumUpLemma(nums[0..ln], [nums[ln]]);
      }
      sumUp(nums[0..ln]) + sumUp([nums[ln]]);
      {
        assert forall a:: sumUp([a]) == a;
      }
      sumUp(nums[0..ln]) + nums[ln];
      {
        sumsEqual(nums[0..ln]);
      }
      sumDown(nums[0..ln]) + nums[ln];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again. Here is what it was for. https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/leetcode/FindPivotIndex.dfy